# Probability that the white balls remains the same in urn 2

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let the urn $U_1$ with $m_1$ white balls and $n_1$ black balls, the urn $U_2$ with $m_2$ white balls and $n_2$ black balls. A balanced die is rolled and if
an even number appears, a ball, chosen at random from $U_1$, is transferred to
urn $U_2$. If an odd number appears, a ball, chosen at random from urn $U_2$, is
transferred to urn $U_1$. What is the probability that, after the above experiment
is performed twice, the number of white balls in the urn $U_2$ remains the same?

How to organize the events to apply Bayes Theorem? I don't know how to start solve the problem.

Comment: There are 4 distinct equiprobable cases to consider, depending on whether the two rolls of the die result in Even-Even, Even-Odd, Odd-Even, or Odd-Odd.  In each case, the first transfer from *some* urn to the *other* urn will be a black ball, with some probability, and a white ball with some probability.  Then, the second transfer, from from *some* urn to the *other* urn will be a black ball, with some probability and a white ball with some probability.  ...see next comment

Comment: Each one of the 4 specific (equiprobable) cases determines which urn is the source of the 1st transfer and which urn is the source of the 2nd transfer.

Comment: Given Cases 1 through 4, let $p_k$ denote the probability that the number of white balls in Urn 2 is the same after the two transfers as at the start of the problem, **given that Case** $k$ pertains $~: ~k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then the desired computation is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} \times \left[\sum_{k=1}^4 p_k\right].$

Comment: Note - *shortcut*: if, in a specific Case, the same urn is the **source** of the two transfers, then in that specific Case, the only way that the number of white balls in Urn 2 is unchanged after the two transfers, is if both transfers were a black ball.

Comment: Note - *pitfall*: suppose (for example) that the two rolls of the die resulted in Even-Even, which implies that Urn 1 is the source of both transfers.  **Regardless** of whether the first transfer is a black or white ball, the probability of the 2nd transfer being a black ball will be **different** from the probability that the 1st transfer is a black ball.  This is because after the first transfer, **Urn 1 has changed**, re how many black &/or white balls that it contains.